# Removing i386 and x86_64 from an embedded Cocoa Touch framework when archiving

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, app-store-connect, urbanairship.com

Urban Airship provides an iOS 8+ framework called AirshipKit.framework. Linking and embedding this framework works fine in both the simulator and device. However, when I go to archive the binary and validate it, iTunes Connect says the app contains code for unsupported architectures i386 and x86_64. How can I get Xcode to remove support for these architectures from the archived app?

Under Build Settings I have:

- **Architectures:** Standard architectures (armv7, armv7s)
- **Build Active Architecture Only:** Yes for debug, No for release
- **Supported Platforms:** iOS
- **Valid Architectures:** arm64 armv7 armv7s

Comment: Added my build settings to the question... I think they are correct.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [lipo](http://ss64.com/osx/lipo.html) to extract the arm code to a new file and submit that one, but it sounds like something is very wrong - you shouldn't need to do anything like this to submit, it might be a bug in Xcode. Which version are you using? Did any other settings in the build get changed (the text would be **bold** if the build setting is modified from the default)?

Answer (score 1):

There is a new version of the Urban Airship SDK, 5.0.3 
Are you still seeing this issue when building with the new Framework version?

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same problem for a couple of days until I realized my own idiocy. My app is set to support 7.0+ and yet I still had the Airship.framework, which as the UA (Urban Airship) documentation strictly recommends, was only to be used for 8.0 + 
I removed the framework and the validation came back success!

So if your app is inclusive of 7.0 or lower, then all you need is the libUAirship-5+ library. As @aschuman suggested, there is a new one available (libUAirship-5.0.3.a)